# Timefold benchmark can't find benchmark.xml

Tags: timefold

I'm trying to use the Timefold benchmark tools by following along in the user guide. I'm using Timefold 1.3.0 with Java 17 on Windows 11.

I have a simple project that starts like this:

```java
public class TimefoldBenchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PlannerBenchmarkFactory benchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource("benchmarkConfig.xml");
```

When I run, I immediately get this exception on the `PlannerBenchmarkFactory` line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The XML schema (/benchmark.xsd) does not exist.
Maybe build the sources with Maven first?
    at ai.timefold.solver.core.impl@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.io.jaxb.GenericJaxbIO.readSchemaResource(GenericJaxbIO.java:112)
    at ai.timefold.solver.core.impl@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.io.jaxb.GenericJaxbIO.validate(GenericJaxbIO.java:248)
    at ai.timefold.solver.benchmark@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.benchmark.impl.io.PlannerBenchmarkConfigIO.read(PlannerBenchmarkConfigIO.java:24)
    at ai.timefold.solver.benchmark@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlReader(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:210)
    at ai.timefold.solver.benchmark@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlInputStream(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:186)
    at ai.timefold.solver.benchmark@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlResource(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:127)
    at ai.timefold.solver.benchmark@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlResource(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:102)
    at ai.timefold.solver.benchmark@1.3.0/ai.timefold.solver.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(PlannerBenchmarkFactory.java:102)
    at com.soartech.peirce.eval/com.soartech.peirce.eval.TimefoldBenchmark.main(TimefoldBenchmark.java:28)
```

My benchmark file looks like just the blueprint example in the user guide, except I'm making the problems programmatically (but it never gets to that part of the code).

I looked in `timefold-solver-benchmark-1.3.0.jar` and `benchmark.xsd` in indeed there in the root of the jar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In tracing through the code that tries to load benchmark.xsd, it looks like it's trying to load it from timefold-solver-core-impl-1.3.0.jar, which does NOT have this file. Not sure why it's trying to load from there instead of timefold-solver-benchmark-1.3.0.jar.

Comment: I also tested it with optaplanner 9.44 and I get the same exception.

Comment: I smell some kind of issue with modularity. We don't really test the solver with JPMS, for us it's classpath only. It's entirely possible that running within JPMS is broken; pull requests welcome.

Comment: It looks like you're right. If I remove the module-info.java from the project then it gets past that line. Not ideal, but this is just a benchmarking project so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the method to load the benchmark configuration, `createFromXmlResource`, your `benchmark.xml` file should be in the resource folder.

Comment: It's not my benchmark.xml. It's the one in the root of timefold-solver-benchmark-1.3.0.jar.